# Create a coupon in Woocommerce with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two different sites. Site1 is the wordpress site. Site2 is the other site. What I'm trying to do is create a coupon in site1's database from site2. I have successfully connected to site1's database, and I am able to make mysql queries. Now, how do I create a woocommerce coupon from site2 only using mysql. (site2 is built in node.js)

I want to do something like this (this wont work ofcourse but something like this)

```
INSERT INTO wp58_posts(post_title, post_status, comment_status,ping_status, post_password, post_name, post_type )values('testcoupon', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', 'testcoupon', 'shop_coupon');
```

Comment: Post the code you've already tried if you want help.

Comment: I do not know how to do it and have therefore not coded

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you bring us a problem and expect us to code a custom solution for you.  If you are unable to write your own code, I would suggest you hire a professional developer.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad written question. What i was looking for was someone who already have done it before or know the Wordpress database better than me. I'm in a learning phase and was hoping that someone with some more knowledge to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All magic - [Create a coupon programatically](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/)

**Or**

```php
$coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE'; // Code
$amount = '10'; // Amount
$discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product
$wp_prefix = 'wp_'; 
$post_author = 1;  // post author ID

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}posts` 
(`post_title`, `post_content`, `post_status`, `post_author`, `post_type`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_code}, '', 'publish', {$post_author}, 'shop_coupon')";

$coupon_id = $last_inser_id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'discount_type', {$discount_type})";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'coupon_amount', {$amount})";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'individual_use', 'no')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'product_ids', '')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'exclude_product_ids', '')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'usage_limit', '')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'expiry_date', '')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$wp_prefix}postmeta` 
(`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
  VALUES 
({$coupon_id}, 'free_shipping', 'no')";
```

Comment: I tried it out but it didnt work 

INSERT INTO wp58_posts(post_title, post_content, post_status ,post_author,post_type)
values('testcoupon', '', 'publish', '2', 'shop_coupon');

i get Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'post_date' at row 1

Comment: Use `NOW()` for this column.

Comment: It worked for that col, now i got  Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'post_date_gmt' at row 1

Comment: Use `NOW()` for all datetime fields.

Comment: nvm i fixed it with this query 

INSERT INTO wordpress.wp58_posts(post_date,post_date_gmt,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_excerpt,to_ping,pinged,post_content_filtered,post_title, post_content, post_status ,post_author,post_type)values(NOW(),NOW(),NOW(),NOW(),'testhuheuhe','','','','testcoupon', '', 'publish', '2', 'shop_coupon');
/*select * from wordpress.wp58_posts where post_type = "shop_coupon";

now i just need to fix the postmeta right?

Comment: Right, and pay attention to `meta_key`  and `meta_value`. All the coupon settings are saved in them.